# simple_form renders radio buttons incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rendering, simple-form

Using simple_form I render some radio buttons to select Gender on registration page.

code:

```
        = f.input :gender,
              :collection => gender,
              :as => :radio_buttons,
              :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

This gives output like:

[image]

Is there a way to make the first radio button be behind Male and the 2nd radio button behind Female?

Comment: Have you checked that the html it produces is wrong? Because it looks like a styling issue to me.

Comment: What's the content of the `gender` variable/method? Is it an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a better solution than my original below.

From the code:

```
#   form_for @user do |f|
#     f.collection_radio_buttons(
#       :options, [[true, 'Yes'] ,[false, 'No']], :first, :last
#     ) do |b|
#       b.label { b.radio_button + b.text }
#     end
#   end
```

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(
    :gender, [['Male', 'Male'], ['Male', 'Male']], :first, :last
  ) do |b|
    b.label { b.text + b.radio_button }
  end
%>
```

You can even add other helpers like `image_tag` in there too:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(
    :gender, [['Male', 'Male'], ['Male', 'Male']], :first, :last
  ) do |b|
    b.label { image_tag("#{b.text}.png") + b.radio_button }
  end
%>
```

This solution is not a normal custom component.  This custom compontent inherits from CollectRadioButtonsInput instead of the normal CollectionInput class.  I modified the 2 relevant methods.

Inside `app/inputs/radio_buttons_left_label_input.rb`

```
class RadioButtonsLeftLabelInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionRadioButtonsInput
  def input
    label_method, value_method = detect_collection_methods

    @builder.send("collection_radio_buttons",
      attribute_name, collection, value_method, label_method,
      input_options, input_html_options, &collection_block_for_nested_boolean_style
    )
  end

  protected

  def build_nested_boolean_style_item_tag(collection_builder)
    collection_builder.text.html_safe + collection_builder.radio_button.html_safe
  end
end
```

It can be used like this

```
<%= form.input :gender,
  :as => :radio_buttons_left_label,
  :collection => %w[Female Male]
%>
```

Comment: Have to give this a try thx for posting ;) if its working i grant the question thx

Comment: Hi @Rubytastic how did you go?  Did you see my lastest edit?  I put it at the top and it is the correct way to do what you asked, no hacks required.  I finally found it as a comment in the simple_form code.

Comment: Still not fully working I made a followup on this since this post is getting a mess, granted for the post back on this.  There seems a strange issue with your code resulting in numbers being printed. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272764/simple-form-render-image-x-label-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the exact thing, but there is something called order which can be assigned which tag to be displayed first e.g. [:label, :input] and also inlining may help here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to simply create or sort the collection in the order which you want?

Somethink like this :

```
= f.input :gender,
    :collection => gender.reverse,
    :as => :radio_buttons,
    :item_wrapper_class => 'inline'
```

Obviously, this is not the better solution. You should create the list in the right order.

Comment: Thx for the comment it indeed just swaps the buttons wich is no solution, the problem is like in the image that "Gender" (label) is right before the first radio button where that should have been "Male" then a (*)Female