# simple_form render radio button group with  <image>( X ) Label with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Im trying for some time to use simple_form to create the below example but + the label and fixing some styling. Anyone knows how to fix:

- remove the **2**'s no idea where they come from (seems strange i18n bug on production it throws a whole bunch of I18n in )
- Have the text Male or Female after the radio button

[image: label output]

Is the result from below code:

```
     .clear
    = f.label "Gender"
    = f.collection_radio_buttons(:gender, [['Male', 'icon_male'], ['Female', 'icon_female']],
                                 :first, :last,
                                 :item_wrapper_class => 'horizontal',
                                 ) do |gender|
      = gender.label { image_tag("/assets/icons/16x16/#{gender.text}.png") + gender.radio_button  }

    .clear
    .ruler
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.clear` and `.ruler` stuff?  In fact every thing outside the collection_radio_buttons. It would be good to isolate the code to confirm that the bug is within the collection radio_buttons.

Comment: Tried that it is inside the simple_form code

Comment: Is there a way to do this and get rid of the radio selection button and just use a Boostrap button or an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final working snippet:

```
= f.label "Gender"
- f.collection_radio_buttons(:gender, [['Male', 'icon_male'], ['Female', 'icon_female']], :first, :last, :item_wrapper_class => 'horizontal') do |gender|
  = gender.label { image_tag("/assets/icons/16x16/#{gender.text}.png") + gender.radio_button  }
.clear
.ruler
```

Answer (score 10):

To remove the 2s and get the text label in there on the right use:

```
= f.label "Gender"
= f.collection_radio_buttons(:gender, [['Male', 'icon_male'], ['Female', 'icon_female']],
                             :first, :last,
                             :item_wrapper_class => 'horizontal',
                             ) { |gender| gender.label { image_tag("/assets/icons/16x16/#{gender.text}.png") + gender.radio_button + gender.text } }
```

Removing the `=` before the `gender.label` will remove the 2s.

Comment: what happens if you change it to a `-`

Comment: HAML   ( = output to screen _( ( - calculate la value ) so that will do nothing...

Comment: Yes thats really just not a solution, I have now removed the icons, it must be me really being newbie here or this is really not easy accomplised. Guess ill be digging the simple_form source codes soon to figure it out in the end

Comment: I just want confirmation that you have tried it so i can continue helping you debug the problem.

Comment: Yes I have tried it but this is basics HAML = means output to screen  HAML - means calculate or call function

Comment: Rubytastic You should upvote 23inhouse's answer on changing to a -, I did. He is correct on changing the - but he might have said to do it to the wrong element. See my answer. The difference is = will render the output of the iterator. - will suppress it. These translate to erb's <%- and <%= minus the "<%". I tried your code in my answer and it does indeed fix the error. (minus the extra comma)

Comment: How can I get rid of the little radio button?

Answer (score 8):

Rubytastic you have an extra comma in your answer.
Here is the correct code that @23inhouse was suggesting. It works for me in

- rails 3.1.3
- simple form 2.0.2
- haml 3.1.4
- haml-rails 0.3.4

```
    = simple_form_for @object_new do |f|
      .clear
      = f.label "Gender"
      - f.collection_radio_buttons(:gender, [['Male', 'icon_male'], ['Female', 'icon_female']], :first, :last, :item_wrapper_class => 'horizontal') do |gender|
        = gender.label { image_tag("rails.png") + gender.radio_button  }
      .clear
      .ruler
```

Comment: Thank you @engineerDave, Rubytastic is repeatedly creating bounties to get the correct answer, then stating there is a problem in the answer and then not paying the bounty for the question. :-(

Comment: I shall try this and if its my fault then grand the question as approved. I do not repeatedly create new bounties without paying bounty. I don't do much bounties at all from time to time.

Comment: Ok then fair is fair, I've updated question with the total correct syntax it shall be then. The initial comment didn't work and maybe I was to short around the corner no hard feelings ;) I shall let it expire so you both get 50% of the bounty wich Guess is fairest solution.

Comment: I correctly answered this question the last time asked it about a month.  That question also had a bounty which you didn't reward.  Same question, same answer... answered a month ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011970/simple-form-renders-radio-buttons-incorrectly/10907366#10907366

Comment: You can just give the bounty to @23inhouse. No biggie. I've been doing Rails for a while but only recently started paying attention to my SO points.:-) Just trying to contribute where/when I can. This was too minor of an edit IMO (on my part) to get bounty points. Good luck in your learning of Rails!