# Rails simple_form styling radio buttons with font-awesome

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, simple-form

I am using simple_form along with Font-Awesome in Rail to create my forms. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272764/simple-form-render-radio-button-group-with-image-x-label-with-twitter-boot) provided in here shows how to use an image in place of the radio buttons but I have been unsuccessful in applying the icon with font-awesome which is a bit different.

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
```

**My Code**

```
 <%= r.collection_radio_buttons( :status, [[0, 'Yes'] ,[1, 'No']], :first, :last,:item_wrapper_class => "horizontal") do |like| like.label { fa_icon ("fa-smile-o") + like.radio_button} end  %>
```

I want to style radio buttons so that the font-awesome icon replaces the checkbox and that when selected, it should show a color change.

This [Jsfiddle](http://codepen.io/rstrahl/pen/yyEYBx) shows how to do it which is coded in HTML/CSS but I do not know how to apply it to the simple_form syntax.

Comment: simple_form generates usual html code. code in jsfiddle should work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<%= r.collection_radio_buttons( :status, [[0, 'Yes'] ,[1, 'No']], :first, :last,:item_wrapper_class => "horizontal with-font") %>
```

It should give you a selector to work with (`.with-font`) and the rest you can do with the css like in the fiddle...