# How to generate a radio-inline label with simple_form and bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I'm using:

```
<%= simple_form_for @visitor, html: {class: 'form-inline'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :favorite, label: false, as: :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.submit "Choose!", :class => "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

And I get this html:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons required visitor_favourite">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio">
            <input class="radio_buttons required" id="visitor_favourite_true" name="visitor[favourite]" type="radio" value="true" />
            Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio">
            <input class="radio_buttons required" id="visitor_favourite_false" name="visitor[favourite]" type="radio" value="false" />
            No
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I'm looking for is a way to generate the labels as radio-inline because that is the style i want:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
```

There is a similar question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/plataformatec-simpleform/radio-inline/plataformatec-simpleform/luBwsduu9mk/sogbhsDt8O4J) but for the "radio inline" class and desn't work as to generate radio-inline.

I'm using simple_form 3.0.2 and tried 3.1.0rc2 and Bootstrap 3.2.0 with rails 4.1.4
Anyway or method to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By getting inspiration form this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011970/simple-form-renders-radio-buttons-incorrectly) I managed to do it by creating a :radio_buttons_inline input type.

Create the file:

```
app/inputs/radio_buttons_inline_input.rb
```

with this content:

```
class RadioButtonsInlineInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionRadioButtonsInput
  def input
    label_method, value_method = detect_collection_methods
    @builder.send("collection_radio_buttons", attribute_name, collection, value_method,
      label_method, input_options, input_html_options, 
      &collection_block_for_nested_boolean_style)
  end

  protected
    def item_wrapper_class
      "radio-inline"
    end
end
```

And then use it in your view like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @visitor do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
     <%= f.input :favourite, :as => :radio_buttons_inline%>
<% end %>
```

This renders the html as:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons_inline required visitor_favourite">
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="radio_buttons_inline required" id="visitor_favourite_true" name="visitor[favourite]" type="radio" value="true" />
               Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="radio_buttons_inline required" id="visitor_favourite_false" name="visitor[favourite]" type="radio" value="false" />
            No
        </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

I got the following to work under simple_form 3.1.0:

```
f.input :favorite, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, 
        item_label_class: "radio-inline", item_wrapper_tag: false
```

Comment: Cool! Many thanks, can it be implemented like wrapper? Somehow like ```f.input :favorite, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, wrapper: "radio_inline'```

Answer (score 1):

Here is for Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <%= f.label :favorite, class: "form-check-label" do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :favorite, true, false, class: "form-check-input" %> Yes
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <%= f.label :favorite, class: "form-check-label" do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :favorite, false, false, class: "form-check-input" %> No
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just pass in:

```
item_wrapper_class: 'inline'
```

It'll look like:

```
 <%= f.input :favorite, label: false, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'inline'  %>
```

And it should work.

Comment: No it doesn't and that's the link a put to the similar question. it doesn't work because item_wrapper_class adds a class to the label. So you can get <label class="radio inline"> or <label class="radio radio-inline"> but not <label class="radio-inline">