# How to use label.radio-inline instead of span.radio-inline > label with bootstrap 3 and simple_form 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I use bootstrap v3.3.1 and simple_form 3.1.0.

I wrote `f.input :some_column, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'radio-inline'` in a horizontal form.
And simple_form 3.0.2 generates `label.radio-inline > input`, but simple_form 3.1.0 generates `span.radio-inline > label > input`.

It seems bootstrap's `Inline checkboxes and radios` assumes label without span. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls )
How to remove span and set `radio-inline` class to inline labels?

- I tried `item_wrapper_tag: false` and I can remove `span`, but I cannot set `radio-inline` class to inline labels.
- I tried `label_html: { class: 'radio-inline' }`, and it sets class to label of left column instead of inline labels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a radio-inline label with simple\_form and bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352643/how-to-generate-a-radio-inline-label-with-simple-form-and-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple radio button inline solution

**CSS**

```
.radio-buttons-inline{
    .make-md-column(12);
}

.radio-buttons-inline {
    .margin-right(10px);
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="radio-buttons-inline">
    <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option1">1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option1">2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option1">3
    </label>
 <hr>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9291/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to use methods of simple_form gem instead of HTML directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but for anyone out there looking for an answer and found this thread I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
f.input :some_column, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'radio-inline', item_wrapper_tag: 'label'
```